# How to filter an unknown element in a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I'm trying to make a program that is given abbreviations of the days of the week (Mon, Tue, Wed etc.) and replaces these with the full word (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday). The program creates a list full of strings and outputs it as a string. I have this working except for when something that isn't a day of the week is used. For example, a word that isn't Mon, Tue, Wed etc. (As seen in the code) I want to be able to filter out the unwanted word but don't know how to. Please help.

The code:

```
days = []

def format_days(days): 

  days = [d.replace('Mon', 'Monday') for d in days]
  days = [d.replace('Tue', 'Tuesday') for d in days]
  days = [d.replace('Wed', 'Wednesday') for d in days]
  days = [d.replace('Thu', 'Thursday') for d in days]
  days = [d.replace('Fri', 'Friday') for d in days]
  days = [d.replace('Sat', 'Saturday') for d in days]
  days = [d.replace('Sun', 'Sunday') for d in days]


  return days

answer = format_days(['Sat', 'Fun', 'Tue', 'Thu'])
print(answer)

# ['Saturday', 'Fun', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday'] <-- This is the output

# ['Saturday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday'] <-- This is the output I want
```

I want to be able to filter out 'fun' from the list but the code needs to work for everything that isn't: Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun not just 'fun'

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it? Did you try using something some sort of `if` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a dictionary of valid words. If anything other than a valid day is encountered it's ignored.

```
def fromat_days(days):
    valid_days={'Mon':'Monday',
                'Tue':'Tuesday',
                 ...
                'Sun':'Sunday'}
    return [valid_days[day] for day in days if day in valid_days]
```

Comment: Glad to help ;) @skribbsta

Comment: @Ch3steR I have the same question.

Comment: @RoadRunner Looks like someone's on a downvoting spree. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you a different approach for this. Start by defining a dictionary mapping the three first letters of a day to the entire name:

```
days_of_week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
d = {day[:3]:day for day in days_of_week}

print(d)

{'Mon': 'Monday',
 'Tue': 'Tuesday',
 'Wed': 'Wednesday',
 'Thu': 'Thursday',
 'Fri': 'Friday',
 'Sat': 'Saturday',
 'Sun': 'Sunday'}
```

And use a list comprehension with a conditional statement so that nothing is returned if a given case is not found in the dictionary:

```
[d.get(i) for i in ['Sat', 'Fun', 'Tue', 'Thu'] if i in d]
# ['Saturday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday']
```

Comment: Then why did you post it if it is the same as the (two!) existing other answers?

Comment: It was posted more or less on the same time (I tool longer since I took my time in adding explanations) @mkrieger1

Comment: Nice answer. I was lazy and just used the `calendar` module instead. Also not sure why you need `get(i)` here since you already checking `if i in d`. `get()` returns `None` if the key is not found by default, but that will never happen `if i in d` is `True` anyways. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: Yes you're right. Left it there cause I was thinking of doing it differently I think :) but youre right, not really necessary @road

Answer (score 2):

Adding to others answers, you could also use the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/calendar.html) functions [`day_name`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_name) and [`day_abbr`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_abbr) to [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) day abbreviations and full weekday names:

```
from calendar import day_abbr, day_name

day_map = dict(zip(day_abbr, day_name))

days = ['Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri', 'Sat']

print([day_map[d] for d in days if d in days])
# ['Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
```

This is helpful because you don't have to generate the day dictionary yourself.

Comment: Nice answer. Never knew the `calender` module. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a mapping from abbreviations to full names and then only replace if the abbreviation is present in the mapping:

```
map_to_names = {'Mon': 'Monday', 'Tue': 'Tuesday', ..., 'Sun': 'Sunday'}
result = [map_to_names[s] for s in days if s in map_to_names]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store in a dict the mapping btw the first 3 characters and the day:

```
w_day = {'Mon': 'Monday',
 'Tue': 'Tuesday',
 'Wed': 'Wednesday',
 'Thu': 'Thursday',
 'Fri': 'Friday',
 'Sat': 'Saturday',
 'Sun': 'Sunday'}

def format_days(days): 
    return list(filter(None, map(w_day.get, days)))

format_days(['Sat', 'Fun', 'Tue', 'Thu'])
```

output:

```
['Saturday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday']
```